# error 404 while accessing api

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I am using PHP codeigniter and chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver.

My directory structure is as below

```
├───cache
├───config
├───controllers    <-- api.php
│   └───api
├───core
├───helpers
├───hooks
├───language
│   ├───bulgarian
│   ├───english
│   └───portuguese-brazilian
├───libraries
├───logs
├───models
├───third_party
└───views
    └───errors
        ├───cli
        └───html
```

my .htaccess is as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

I edited my config.php entry

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Everything is working absolutely perfect on my local laptop. 
When I moved my code to server, it not working.

for example, access url like `http://www.example.com/pal/api/class/` -geting 404

while, if I do locally : `http://localhost:88/pal/api/class/`  its returning my output JSON

I noticed, in log file on server (not on local) url actually rendering like `http://www.example.com/pal/api/class/index`

**I am assuming that /index in end of url is causing problem.**

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?
I scanned and clear for all hardcord "localhost" in my code before moving to server ...

```
**my **routes.php** is as below**

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: What web hosting provider are you trying to use? If it's GoDaddy then you will have to monkey around with the `.htaccess` a bit.

Comment: I am using gungoos right now to testing... is fix of this problem is .htaccess only ?

Comment: I have no experience with GunGoos, sorry.

Comment: Does GunGoos use Apache? Looking at their homepage I can see the server is identifying itself as NGINX.

Comment: yes they have apache. I also try on acquia. same issue, url are render with /index in last.  On my local laptop I am using XAMPP ... and non of these cloud offer XAMPP. Is that a problem? technically I don;t think so.

Comment: Where is your index.php file located? What does your CodeIgniter routes.php file look like?

Comment: I add my routes.php above. I did setting to get rid of index.php ... and I have separate front end folder at level of application folder